# SPA login system not working using ajax/jquery/php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, get

I am creating a single page app. Upon initial load of the page, I want to see a login form, and a registration form (which I do). Upon login, I am supposed to see a profile page - however a blank page appears, and the URL reads: `localhost/xxx/checklogin.php`. I think this means that my app is getting stuck on the checklogin.php script for some reason. Here is some code - so you can start to understand my problem:

js/application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //load login form
    $.get('templates/loginform.php', function(data) {
        $('#login').html(data);
    });

    //load registration form
    $.get('templates/regform.php', function(data) {
        $('#register').html(data);
    });    

    //on login form submit do
    $("#loginform").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('#myusername').val() != '' || $('#mypassword').val() != '') {
            $.post("checklogin.php", $(this).serialize(), function() {
                $.get("templates/login_success.php", function(data) {
                    $("#main").html(data);
                    $("#login").remove();
                    $("#register").remove();
                });
            });
        } else {
            alert('Please enter a Username/Password');
        }
    });
});
```

I have also tried:

js/application.js

```
...

$("#loginform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#myusername').val() != '' || $('#mypassword').val() != '') {
        $.post("checklogin.php", $(this).serialize(), function() {
            $("#main").load("templates/login_success.php");
            $("#login").remove();
            $("#register").remove();
        });
    } else {
            alert('Please enter a Username/Password');
    }
});

...
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>it IT</title>
    <script src="reqscripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/application.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Solid' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="login"></div>
    <div id="register"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

templates/loginform.php

```
<?php
session_start(); 
?>

<form id="loginform" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
    <h1 class="textaligncenter">Login</h1>
     <div id="loginuser">
        <input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername">
    </div>
    <div id="usertext">
        <p>Username:</p>
    </div>
    <div id="loginpass">
        <input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword">
    </div>
    <div id="passtext">
        <p>Password:</p>
    </div>
    <div id="submitbutton">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
    </div>
</form>
```

First (in application.js), the registration form, and the login form get loaded. Upon login - the jquery checks if the fields have content, then executes a post call to the checklogin.php script. This script does everything needed to login the user. On the post call's success - `templates/login_success.php` gets loaded into the `main` div, and the login and registration forms get removed. Like I said above, the app doesn't seem to get past the post call from within the form submit function.

Comment: Quick note: `session_start();` needs to be in every `.php` file used. *Just so you know*.

Comment: @Fred do i need it on my index page if it is already in the template that is being loaded onto the index page?

Comment: It's best to do so, yes. Try different combinations.

Comment: @Fred I added `session_start()` to my index.php and still the same problem - i have it on all my other php pages...

Comment: @Fred I think I got it...I had to move some jquery around - ill answer my own question...can you take a look at it and maybe explain the flow to me?

Comment: Might be something inside your `checklogin.php` - any way of posting it in your question?

Comment: I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to move the login form submit function inside of the initial get request to the login form like so:

js/application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('templates/loginform.php', function(data) {
        $('#login').html(data);

        $("#loginform").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($('#myusername').val() != '' || $('#mypassword').val() != '') {
                $.post("checklogin.php", $(this).serialize(), function() {
                    $("#main").load("templates/login_success.php");
                    $("#login").remove();
                    $("#register").remove();
                });
            } else {
                alert('Please enter a Username/Password');
            }
        });
    });

    $.get('templates/regform.php', function(data) {
        $('#register').html(data);
    });
});
```

I just need someone to verify that this is correct - I don't want buggy code!

Comment: I'm certainly not a `pro`, but from what I know so far, I'd say that looks about right. Hey, if it works and it looks good, then I'd say it's perfect ;-)

Comment: @Fred thanks! i just ran into another problem though :( regarding my registration script...im going to make a new question...this one is weird - ill post the url to it

Comment: I might not respond right away, connection problems here. Am troubleshooting.

Comment: @Fred thats cool - whenever you can - here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240718/spa-simple-registration-username-stored-as-root-instead-of-given-username