# SPA simple registration username stored as "root" instead of given username

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, registration

I am creating a simple `SPA` member registration system. Upon registration - the user gets stored in the database - and redirected to a profile page. Seems fairly simple, however, after trying to register as "joe", with password, "joe", and email, "joe@joe.com", I get redirected to a profile page which displays that my username is "root". I have checked to make sure my mysqli connection variable `$username` is not getting mixed in with the storing of data (as that has the value of "root"). Here is my code:

checkreglogin.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="bonjour3"; // Mysql password
$db_name="itit"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
$mysqli = new mysqli("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name")or die("cannot connect");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword
$rmyusername=$_POST['rmyusername'];
$rmypassword=$_POST['rmypassword'];
$myemail=$_POST['myemail'];

$sql2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username=? and password=?");
$sql2->bind_param('ss',$rmyusername,$rmypassword);
$sql2->execute();
$sql2->store_result();//apply to prepare statement
$numRows = $sql2->num_rows;
if($numRows != null) {
    echo "Username taken.";
    session_destroy();
}
else {
    // Insert data into mysql
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name(username, password, email)VALUES(?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $rmyusername, $rmypassword, $myemail);
    $stmt->execute();

    $_SESSION['username'] = $rmyusername;
}
?>
```

The above script gets run when a user registers. Then they get "redirected" (not really because it's an SPA) to the profile page below:

templates/login_success.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<h1>Login Successful</h1>
<h2>Username: <? echo $_SESSION['username']?></h2>
<div id="logoutlinkdiv" >
    <a href = "#" >Log out</a>
</div>
```

The username should show "joe" where it says `<? echo $_SESSION['username']?>`, however it says "root" instead...

**UPDATE**

js/application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.get('templates/regform.php', function(data) {
    $('#register').html(data);

    $("#registerform").submit(function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('#rmyusername').val() != '' || $('#rmypassword').val() != '' || $('#myemail').val() != '') {
            if(!isValidEmailAddress($('#myemail').val())) {
                alert("Please enter a valid email address");
            }
            else {
                $.post("checkreglogin.php", $(this).serialize(), function(){
                    $("#main").load("templates/login_success.php");
                    $("#login").remove();
                    $("#register").remove();
                });
            }
        } else {
            alert('Please enter a Username/Password and email.');
        }
    });
}); 
});
```

**UPDATE**

I changed the `$_POST` calls to `$_GET` calls, and I used the url to create a user, and it worked - however I get a blank page with a warning on it:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /Users/Eamon/Sites/checkreglogin.php:1) in /Users/Eamon/Sites/checkreglogin.php on line 3
```

Comment: You're also writing a record to the database with the same variable - is that written to the database properly?

Comment: @andrewsi im not sure what you mean by "same variable"....which variable are you referring to?

Comment: You're setting `$_SESSION['username']` to `$rmyusername;`; $rmyusername is also used in your INSERT statement. Is that adding records to the database with the right username, or is root showing up there, too?

Comment: @andrewsi oh...i understand - and to answer your question...the user DOES NOT get created after registration (it doesn't show up in the database) - so something is going wrong there...i got rid of the first `$_SESSION['username'] = $rmyusername;` line as I dont think it is neccessary - ill edit my code above

Comment: Do you know which branch of the if statement is being called? Is it trying (and failing) to INSERT the new user, or is it running through the 'Username taken' code? Also, there's nothing in the code that you've given that does a redirect - how are you dealing with that?

Comment: @andrewsi the redirect happens with jquery - i'll post the code - i'll put in an echo statement to see where the program is going.

Comment: @andrewsi i put `echo "here";` in the else statement of checkreglogin.php and it never gets executed...if the program goes to the if statement...it should say "Username taken." and that isn't happening...so it doesnt seem like it is making it to the if/else block

Comment: I'd suggest changing the PHP code while you debug, so it's looking for variables in GET rather than POST; that will mean you can call it directly in the browser, and pass variables in using the URL.

Comment: @andrewsi can you give me an example?

Comment: `checkreglogin.php?rmyusername=fred&rmypassword=pass&myemail=me@me.com` will let you access the same variables in $_GET['rmyusername'], and so on. It'll mean you can run the PHP directly - you can swap it back once you're sure it's working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32176/discussion-between-ewizard-and-andrewsi)

Comment: Alas, I can't really do chat (plus I've got an imminent meeting)

Comment: @andrewsi ok...i made some progress though because of your last comment...I changed the `$_POST` calls to `$_GET` calls - and use the url you suggested...and the user gets created...but i get a warning...ill update my question to show it

Comment: There would seem to be an extra character being sent in your checkreglogin.php, on the very first line - possibly a control character or something? Even if it's something like ` <?php`, the initial space will be enough to cause an error.

Comment: @andrewsi thanks...got rid of the warning...it was that - now i just see a blank page...the profile page (login_success.php) isn't showing up..the user is being created

Comment: Then I'd say it's time to swap your GETs back to POSTs and try with the jquery again!

Comment: @andrewsi woooohoooo u got it...if u want to post some sort of answer ill give you credit!

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer and accept it when you can. I'm happy just to have helped.

Comment: @ewizard Shouldn't that be `<? echo $_SESSION['rmyusername']?>` instead of `<? echo $_SESSION['username']?>`? - I just got back, like an hour after speaking with tech support. However I won't have much time to give you my friend, I've got to get ready for a bunch of things later.

Comment: @ewizard Ah, I just noticed now, that it's resolved. Right on, am glad it worked out.

Comment: Looks like I've gotten my **15 seconds of fame** checkreglogin.php?rmyusername= **fred** &rmypassword=pass&myemail=me@me.com - lol!

Comment: @Fred haha yes you did - one more problem concerning this project though...the if clause that checks if the username and password are filled in isn't working correctly - if i fill in just the username, or just the password then the login_success.php page gets loaded...I only want the page to be loaded if both the password field, and the username field are filled in. Otherwise it should give the alert pop-up message. Do you see anything wrong with my conditions? specifically - `if ($('#rmyusername').val() != '' || $('#rmypassword').val() != '' || $('#myemail').val() != '') {`

Comment: @andrewsi see my above comment to fred...need a little more help

Comment: @ewizard - I think you need to swap the ||s to &&; you want it to run if username isn't empty AND if password isn't empty AND if email isn't empty

Comment: @ewizard The `if ($('#rmyusername').val()...` is that something you tried, or is it giving you a hard time?

Comment: @andrewsi Funny, I was just thinking the very same thing (`&&`).

Comment: @ewizard Try `&&` instead of the `||` (all 3 of them), just like `andrewsi` said.

Comment: @ewizard The `&&` did the trick then(?)

Comment: @ewizard Right on, glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem, found out that in my include('mysqli_connect.php') the variable $username is already taken/used for username for my database connection. It has the same name variable for my registration form.

I change on file mysqli_connect.php in variable $username to $uname = "root"; so that they won't conflict each other